# Commutative Groups and Quotients

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let (A,+) and (B,+) be commutative groups and suppose that A is isomorphic to B. Prove that $A/dA$ is isomorphic to $B/dB$, where $d \in \mathbb{N}$.

Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: We can try $\phi(\operatorname{cl}_A x)=\operatorname{cl}_B(\psi(x))$, where $\psi$ is an isomorphism between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is $cl_Ax$? I have never encountered this notation before.

Comment: It's the equivalence class of the element $x$, here modulo $dA$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: But I think the OP mentioned $dG=\{g\in G|\exists n\in\mathbb N, ng=0\}$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi: G\to H$ is our isomorphism. Define $\phi|_{dG}:dG\to H$ and *show* that it is an injective homomorphism and so is between $dG$ and $dH$. Moreover, $\phi|_{dG}$ is onto (Why?). For your problem, regarding to @Marc's answer, define $\psi:G\to \frac{H}{dH}$ with $\psi(g)=\phi(g)+dH$ and use the first isomorphism theorem for it.

Comment: $\ddot\smile\quad +1$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks again Amy. I am not native and don't know how express my gratitude as it should be. :-)

Comment: You do just fine, native or not!

Answer (score 1):

Morphisms of commutative groups commute with multiplication by an integer. So if $\phi:A\to B$ is an isomorphism then $\phi(dA)=dB$, and so $\phi$ and its inverse pass to the quotient, giving isomorphisms there.